# What is the source of water soaking the passenger side carpet and floor panels on my Pontiac?

Tags: ac, pontiac, g6

I have a 08 Pontiac G6 GT. (Sister car of the Saturn Aura and Chevy Malibu)
Sunroof.

I noticed water on my passenger front and back floor boards. It's clear water and has no smell or weird feel.

I tried drying it out but didn't work. I ripped up the carpet and underneath was another carpet type thing with foam underneath. It was soaked at the bottom. I reached up under the other carpet with the foam and felt directly underneath the dash/glove box. It wasn't wet up that far so I don't think it's leaking from there. I also hear water moving around in behind my dash when i accelerate and turn a certain way.

I went to a glass replacement guy today because maybe my glass needed some TLC and he said, "Now mind me, I'm not an auto body guy but I believe you need a new door seal (front passenger)."

My seats and seat belts are not wet, just the floor boards so I'm kind of leery on the idea of needing new seals.

Any ideas of what it could be and where the ideas are located?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like your A/C drain is plugged. This would account for both the water slosh you hear and for the water on the floor boards on the passenger side. I don't know where it's located at *exactly* on the G6, but it should be under the car on the passenger side just under where the air box for the A/C is at in the engine compartment. Should be a flexible rubber outlet. Stick a straight piece of wire up it. You'll know when you strike gold because it will soak you.

Comment: Paulster2 is straight on, your car actually has a Technical Bulleting on this problem. I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

As @Paulster2 indicated, you likely have a clogged drain, you can use some wire or I prefer metal pipe cleaners.

In addition, you should remove a plug that was installed by the factory incorrectly per a service bulletin to prevent reoccurence. You can see below I have posted the core contents for you at the bottom.

> Stand over the front passenger wheel, look down at fire wall, just off center to the passenger side, near the tunnel that goes down the center of the car, try to find a thin metal shield facing up, behind this shield is the drain tube. it likely has a white plug in it. Using the needle nose pliers and a flat bladed screwdriver, pry off the cap and discard. Take your straw, or wire, and insert in end of tube and gently push in to release the blockage. Once freed, you should see the water come gushing out.

You can use google images to find the exact location if that text isn't enough.
http://lmgtfy.com/?q=pontiac+g6+ac+drain+location

If water does not come out after you unplug the drain, you may have another drain clogged elsehwere as this vehicle has shown to be problematic with this kind of stuff.

**SERVICE BULLETIN:**

> Condition/Concern:
>   This PI was created to inform service Technicians of a white plug/cap that is installed into the end of the evaporator/HVAC housing drain nipple. This plug/cap is part of the production design and intended to be on the HVAC drain for the life of the car. Its purpose is to prevent airflow directly into the HVAC case and aids in part of the "quiet car" initiative.
>
> The HVAC/evaporator drains now through an opening in the bottom of the drain tube rather than at the end of the tube, as it has been previously.
>
> This change was on any Saturn Aura, Pontiac G6 built since October 2007. The new 2008 Chevrolet Malibu since start of production will also have this plug/cap.
>
> Recommendation/Instructions:
>   If there is water on the passenger side front floor area, check the operation of the drain. Make sure that small debris is NOT plugging it up. If so please "REMOVE" the white plug and discard it, to prevent any future reoccurrence of the drain plugging up.
>
> Please follow this diagnostic or repair process thoroughly and complete each step. If the condition exhibited is resolved without completing every step, the remaining steps do not need to be performed.

Comment: FYI the lmgtfy is just easier to post than the actual google url which changes over time. I did it for convenience because the first picture result shows the plug.

Comment: Weed wacker (in the UK strimmer) wire works well for cleaning out long drain pipes.

Comment: Good deal. I didn't post an answer because my GoogleFu just wasn't up to par yesterday. Good call on the service bulletin. +1

Comment: I only knew about it because of a friend having the same issue and vaguely remembering it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer up some experience looking for and analyzing generic water leaks inside passenger cars.  Where does the water come from?

--Air Conditioning (A/C) Condensate. As the finleyarcher answer to this posting tells you, the Heating, Ventilation, Air Conditioning system (HVAC) is one possible point of water entry.  When you are running your car's air conditioner in high humidity hot weather, there is a whole lot of water vapor in the air. That vapor condenses on the surface of the cold evaporator core, and exits a drain.  The drain is generally on the engine side of the dash panel directly in front of the passenger.  You'd be surprised how much water comes out.  In optimal conditions, it wouldn't surprise me to see one cup (8 fluid ounces) in five minutes of operation.  If the drain is clogged that water will go somewhere else. That would be bad.   What I don't understand from you is... its February and I'm assuming this car is in the United States. Not really hot humid weather.  Perhaps there is another source of trouble? Or are we seeing evidence of water from six months ago? (hint: it would be nice to know your location!)

--The other source of water is from adverse weather... rain! There are a whole lot of entry points.  Key points where I've seen troubles.

-- Water overflow at the rain hat.  When it rains, a lot of water goes into the passenger compartment air inlet area at the base of the windshield.  Air goes in, then travels across the top of the cowl and enters the passenger compartment directly in front of the passenger. There is a water separator system there.  There will be a metal or plastic flange that stops water from entering the car.  We always called that part the rain hat.  Here are a couple of photos.  That part is put on the car when the sheet metal is welded up. Its tightly sealed to preclude leakage. The rain hat stops water, so long as the rest of the cowl area drains.  I've seen cars where the cowl drain got stopped up with leaves, water filled up and went over the top of the rain hat. When it does that, the water drips on the floor right in front of the front seat passenger.  (if you told me you park your car under a tree that drops leaves and seeds a lot, this is where I would start my troubleshooting...)  (Do you park your car routinely in such a place?)

[image: Rain hat]

[image: Rain hat too]

--Water from the front tires.  When you are driving in the rain, there is a whole lot of water thrown off the tires.  And that water getting thrown off doesn't go straight down.  Check your inner fenders carefully. Is there any path for water to enter the passenger compartment?

--Sun roof drains.  You didn't tell us if the car has a sun roof or not.  These things can easily leak.  Most manufacturers who install a factory sunroof add FOUR drain hoses, one at each corner.  The hoses run down the sheet metal pillars to drain water out of the bottom of the car.  If those hoses aren't attached well, you'll see water inside the passenger compartment.  (Does this car have a sun roof?)

--Sheet metal junctions.  There is an area at the top of the windshield, inboard about two inches from the side of the car where a bunch of sheet metal joins together.  Its certainly a location that can generate a slight leak.  Usually you will see a slight water spot on the headliner when this happens.

--Door seals, leaking water. Doubtful.  Not likely. The door seals primary purpose is to manage air leaks and reduce noise (so its quiet in your car!)

Info offered here to share a bit of experience troubleshooting water leaks inside vehicles...

Good luck with your troubleshooting and repair.